# Dump dictionary as json file to Google Cloud storage from Jupyter Notebook on Data Proc

Tags: json, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using spark on Google dataproc cluster. I have created a dictionary in Jupyter notebook which I want to dump in my GCS bucket. However, it seems the usual way of dumping to json using fopen() does not work in case of gcp. So, how can I write my dictionary as .json file to GCS. Or, is there any other way to get the dictionary?

It's funny, I could write spark dataframe to gcs without any hassle, but apparently, I can't load JSON on gcs unless I have it on my local system!
Please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The file in GCS is not in your local file system so that's why you cannot call "fopen" on it. You can either save to GCS by directly using a GCS client (for example, [this tutorial](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-write-and-get-a-json-file-in-google-cloud-storage-when-deploying-flask-api-in-google-app-9121fa936d85)), or treat the GCS location as an HDFS destination (for example, saveAsTextFile("gs://...")